# Git "remembers" old not-ignored files

Tags: git, gitignore

I've found a weird problem in Git. I have a folder called *cache* under my Git structure that in the past (by mistake) wasn't *gitignored*. The problem is that some *commits* ago I added this folder to the *.gitignore* file and now due to some cache changes I have noted that some files in this folder are not ignored. Why? How to ignore them definitivelly?

*.gitignore* line is as simple as:

```
cache/*
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [.gitignore file not ignoring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding something to the `.gitignore` does not un-track the file. If you want to un-track the file without deleting it, use `git rm --cached file`. This will remove the file from the index without removing it from the working tree (although you still need to commit this).

It's worth noting that, if you aren't aware, .gitignore only applies to untracked files.